# combine and intercept methods of 2 classes defined by same interface

Tags: c#, interface, intercept

I have a series of classes that implement an interface. I want to create a 3rd class (that also implements the interface) that combines the methods of both classes into a single one, plus add some managing code.
In other words.

Let's say I have this interface:

```
public interface ITestClass
{
    string NamePlusLastName(string name);

    int AgePlus20(int age);

    DateTime YearYouWillDie(int age);
}
```

and I have these 2 classes that implement it:

```
public class TestClassPeter : ITestClass
{
    public string NamePlusLastName(string name)
    {
        return string.Concat(name, " ", "Mc.Cormick");
    }

    public int AgePlus20(int age)
    {
        return age + 40;
    }

    public DateTime YearYouWillDie(int age)
    {
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
}

public class TestClassCharles : ITestClass
{
    public string NamePlusLastName(string name)
    {
        return string.Concat(name, " ", "Gonzales");
    }

    public int AgePlus20(int age)
    {
        return age + 20;
    }

    public DateTime YearYouWillDie(int age)
    {
        return DateTime.Now ;
    }
}
```

I want to create a class that returns an object that implements ITestClass and whose methods are a combination of both classes. Such as:

```
public class TestBoth 
{
    ITestClass peter;
    ITestClass charles;
    ITestClass combinedClass;

    public TestBoth()
    {
        // instantiate classes to be combined.
        peter = new TestClassPeter();
        charles = new TestClassCharles();

        // BEG
        // Add here code that will automatically combine methods of both classes into one.
        // ......
        // END

    }

    // expose as property
    public ITestClass CombinedClass
    {
        get
        {
            return combinedClass;
        }
    }
}
```

so that in the end I can call the combined class like this:

```
TestBoth classBuilder = new TestBoth();
ITestClass combinedClass = classBuilder.combinedClass;

// call a method
string fullName = combinedClass.NamePlusLastName("William");
```

And what is going on behind the scenes is really:

```
string firstValue = peter.NamePlusLastName("William");
// some code here
string secondValue = charles.NamePlusLastName("William");
// some more code here
return finalValue;
```

I want this to happen automatically for all methods. So that way, if I change the Interface definition, and the implementation of Peter and Charles, it will automatically be modified in the classBuilder.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your goal here is... but there may be some fundamental design choices that need to be rethought. Can you talk a little bit about the goal?

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your response. Basically we are transitioning from one data store to another. And might even need to add a 3rd one down the road. So our system needs to have the ability to seamlessly write to all of them at once. We have an interface that defines the methods for the repositories. We want to have a class that will automatically combine the methods to write to all stores and place some arbitration code. (example read from this database, but not that one). We don't want to explicitly implement each method on the combined class. We need it done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Just define a third class that calls both implementations, combine somehow their values and return that result, implementing the interface itself. I don't think there is a need for a *TestBoth*, unless you want to dynamically build that code, which is a completely different way and much more difficult. I would do something like this:

```
public class TestClassPeterAndCharles : ITestClass
{
    private readonly ITestClass peter;
    private readonly ITestClass charles;

    public TestClassPeterAndCharles()
    {
        // Create helper objects from base implementation
        // Alternatively, take them as constructor parameters
        this.peter = new TestClassPeter();
        this.charles = new TestClassCharles();
    }

    public string NamePlusLastName(string name)
    {
        // Get the result from each class and operate on them
        string namePeter = this.peter.NamePlusLastName(name);
        string nameCharles = this.charles.NamePlusLastName(name);
        return namePeter + nameCharles;
    }

    public int AgePlus20(int age)
    {
        int agePeter = this.peter.AgePlus20(age);
        int ageCharles = this.charles.AgePlus20(age);
        return agePeter + ageCharles;
    }

    public DateTime YearYouWillDie(int age)
    {
        DateTime yearPeter = this.peter.YearYouWillDie(age);
        DateTime yearCharles = this.charles.YearYouWillDie(age);
        return yearPeter + yearCharles;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem is I don't want to explicitly implement the methods. I need it done automatically. I was thinking of using reflection, but not sure how and was wondering if somebody has already done this.

Comment: Why is that important for it to be automatic? I don't think there is an easy way to do so, and even it posses problems for the "combine" operation. How can that be done automagically? You need to define what is that, and if it's a case by case, there is no advantage over manual implementation. How it should handle the return values? Should it call the derived methods in a specific order? What about exceptions? I'm thinking that it's far easier to just roll a basic class and do manipulation there, rather than using complicated reflection. It would be easier to debug, and trivial to write.

Comment: The problem is that in my intended application I will have too many methods. The way I will specify the behavior is through attributes in the interface. And some where along the line I will use an enumeration as a parameter to decide what gets called.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a bit of research and tests, I think I arrived to a workable solution. It entails using Unity Intercept and some Reflection.

I will use Unity to create the class whose methods will be intercepted. I will default that class to Peter, and then let the CallHandler determine which methods to fire from which class according to a configuration value.

First, I defined an enumeration that will specify what combination of objects (Peter, Charles or Both) I wish to use:

```
public enum PersonChoice : byte
{
    Peter = 1,

    Charles = 2,

    Both = 3
}
```

This will serve as a global configuration value. I will store it as a property in Peter which will be the class I will intercept. So I define the property and add some constructor logic.

```
public class TestClassPeter : ITestClass
{
    private PersonChoice personChoice;

    // Default Constructor
    public TestClassPeter()
    {
    }

    // Constructor where global personChoice is stored
    public TestClassPeter(PersonChoice personChoice)
    {
        this.personChoice = personChoice;
    }

    public string NamePlusLastName(string name)
    {
        return string.Concat(name, " ", "Mc.Cormick");
    }

    public int AgePlus20(int age)
    {
        return age + 40;
    }

    public DateTime YearYouWillDie(int age)
    {
        return DateTime.Now;
    }

    public PersonChoice PersonChoice
    {
        get{return personChoice;}
    }
}
```

I also needed to add a default constructor to Charles:

```
public class TestClassCharles : ITestClass
{
    public TestClassCharles()
    {
    }
 ...
}
```

I need to tell the interface that defines both Peter and Charles which methods will be intercepted. For that, I created a Handler attribute

```
public class ChoosePersonAttribute : HandlerAttribute
{
    public override ICallHandler CreateHandler(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        return new PersonChoiceHandler();
    }

}
```

and then apply the attribute to my inteface

```
public interface ITestClass
{

    [ChoosePerson]               
    string NamePlusLastName(string name);

    [ChoosePerson]   
    int AgePlus20(int age);

    DateTime YearYouWillDie(int age);
}
```

Next I defined a class that will get me an instance of the object ready to be intercepted.
(notice that the container has  PersonChoice as a parameter for the contructor)

```
public static class Arbitrator
{
    public static ITestClass getInstance(PersonChoice personChoice)
    {
        // Initialize container
        IUnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
        unityContainer.AddNewExtension<Interception>();

        // Associate Interface with object to be intercepted
        unityContainer.RegisterType<ITestClass, TestClassPeter>(new InjectionConstructor(personChoice));
        unityContainer.Configure<Interception>()
            .SetInterceptorFor<ITestClass>(new InterfaceInterceptor());

        // return instance
        return unityContainer.Resolve<ITestClass>();

    }

}
```

Now, I create a sort of facade that gets the instance based on  personChoice

```
public class TestFacade
{
    private ITestClass testClass;

    public TestFacade(PersonChoice personChoice)
    {

        // Get Instance of primary object
        ITestClass combinedClass = Arbitrator.getInstance(personChoice);

        testClass = combinedClass;

    }

    // expose property
    public ITestClass ITester
    {
        get
        {
            return testClass;
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the call Handler code. Using some reflection I get the name of the method being invoked and its parameters. Using the global personChoice paramter I can tell this handler which classes to instantiate and then decide (arbitrate) which methods to call. For this example, for the "Both" option I just decided to add up the return values.

```
public class PersonChoiceHandler : ICallHandler
{
    private WriteOption writeOption;

    private PersonChoice personChoice;

    public PersonChoiceHandler(WriteOption writeOption)
    {
        this.writeOption = writeOption;
    }

    public PersonChoiceHandler()
    {
        this.writeOption = WriteOption.Both;
    }

    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
    {
        // Get personChoice value from object property.
        personChoice = (PersonChoice)Enum.Parse(typeof(PersonChoice),  input.Target.GetType().GetProperty("PersonChoice").GetValue(input.Target, null).ToString());

        // Get Method Name and parameters
        string methodName = input.MethodBase.Name;
        object[] methodArgs = new object[input.Inputs.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Inputs.Count; i++)
        {
            methodArgs[i] = input.Inputs[i];
        }

        Type firstPersonType = null;
        Type secondPersonType = null;
        object firstPersonObject;
        object secondPersonObject;

        // based on personChoice value, instantiate appropriate class and execute the appropriate method .
        switch (personChoice)
        {
            case PersonChoice.Peter:
                firstPersonType = typeof(TestClassPeter);
                break;
            case PersonChoice.Charles:
                firstPersonType = typeof(TestClassCharles);
                break;
            case PersonChoice.Both:
                firstPersonType = typeof(TestClassPeter);
                secondPersonType = typeof(TestClassCharles);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


        // object is instantiated with default constructor. No need to specify PersonChoice property.
        firstPersonObject = Activator.CreateInstance(firstPersonType);
        if (personChoice == PersonChoice.Both)
        {
            secondPersonObject = Activator.CreateInstance(secondPersonType);
        }
        else
        {
            secondPersonObject = null; ;
        }

        // decide method invocation based on PersonChoice
        object firstReturnValue;
        object secondReturnValue;
        switch (personChoice)
        {
            // Call Peter's or Charles' methods
            case PersonChoice.Peter : case PersonChoice.Charles:
                firstReturnValue = firstPersonType.InvokeMember(methodName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, firstPersonObject, methodArgs);
                break;

            // Call Method on Both Peter and Charles and combine results
            case PersonChoice.Both :
                firstReturnValue = firstPersonType.InvokeMember(methodName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, firstPersonObject, methodArgs);
                secondReturnValue = secondPersonType.InvokeMember(methodName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, secondPersonObject, methodArgs);

                // build return value. Done here checking method name as an example.
                if (methodName == "NamePlusLastName")
                {
                    string returnValue = (string)firstReturnValue;
                    firstReturnValue = returnValue + (string)secondReturnValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    int returnValue = (int)firstReturnValue;
                    firstReturnValue = returnValue + (int)secondReturnValue;
                }

                break;

            default:
                firstReturnValue = firstPersonType.InvokeMember(methodName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, firstPersonObject, methodArgs);
                break;
        }

        // Override initial method execution
        IMethodReturn methodReturn = new VirtualMethodReturn(input, null);

        // this down here would have called the original method.
        //var methodReturn = getNext().Invoke(input, getNext);

        // Set the return value
        methodReturn.ReturnValue = firstReturnValue;

        return methodReturn;

    }

    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the example program that does the calls:

```
class TestClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // instantiate my facades
        TestFacade peterFacade = new TestFacade(PersonChoice.Peter);
        TestFacade charlesFacade = new TestFacade(PersonChoice.Charles);
        TestFacade bothFacade = new TestFacade(PersonChoice.Both);

        //      run some methods:
        // Peter
        string name = "Peter";
        int age = 15;
        writeProperties(peterFacade, name, age);

        // Charles
        name = "Charles";
        age = 20;
        writeProperties(charlesFacade, name, age);

        // Both
        name = "Bothergate";
        age = 234;
        writeProperties(bothFacade, name, age);

        // wait for user input.
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void writeProperties(TestFacade facade, string name, int age)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Person name: {0} Last Name: {1} Age : {2} ", name, facade.ITester.NamePlusLastName(name), facade.ITester.AgePlus20(age));
    }
}
```

Finally, here is the program's output:

Person name: Peter Last Name: Peter Mc.Cormick Age: 55

Person name: Charles Last Name: Charles Gonzales Age: 40

Person name: Bothergate Last Name: Bothergate Mc.CormickBothergate Gonzales Age : 528